# how to use recursion to formulate using simple array

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am a beginner in coding .I want to solve the following problem using simple recursion and array. But I can't visualize it. I came up with solution using link list .Following are  problem and my way of solving

> Given n rows of integers, such that the ith row (`1 <= i <= n`)
>   contains i integers. Using the following set of path rules, find the
>   path having the maximum weight.
>
> Path traversal rules:
>
> 1. A valid path sequence would be top-down i.e. begins with the integer in the first row, and traverses all rows selecting only one
>      integer in each row.
> 2. From any jth integer in the ith row i.e. `row[i][j]`, traversal can happen either downward (i.e. to `row[i+1][j]`) or diagonally downward
>      to the right (i.e. to `row[i+1][j+1]`).
>
> The weight of a Path is the sum of values of integers in the Path
>   sequence.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>     No. of Rows: 5 
>         4 
>         2    9 
>         15   1    3 
>         16   92  41  44 
>         8   142  6    4    8
> ```
>
> Expected Output: 4, 2, 15, 92, 142 (Max weight is 255)

Sol.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int n,**ar;

struct n
{
 int i,j;
 int w;
 struct n *ptr;
};

struct n* maxweight(int i,int j,struct n* x)
{
 struct n* tmp=malloc(sizeof(struct n)),*t1,*t2;
 tmp->i=i;
 tmp->j=j;
 tmp->ptr=x;
 tmp->w=ar[i][j];
 if(x)tmp->w+=x->w;
 if(i==n-1)return tmp;
 t1=maxweight(i+1,j,tmp);
 t2=maxweight(i+1,j+1,tmp);
 if(t1->w>t2->w)return t1;
 return t2;
}

int main()
{
 int i,j;
 struct n * s;
 printf("Enter the value of n\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 ar=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  ar[i]=malloc((i+1)*sizeof(int));
  for(j=0;j<=i;j++)scanf("%d",&ar[i][j]);
 }
 s=maxweight(0,0,NULL);
 printf("MAX WEIGHT is :%d\nPATH: ",s->w);
 while(s)
 {
  printf("%d ",ar[s->i][s->j]);
  s=s->ptr;
 }
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}
```

How do I solve this using recursion simply without link-list using n x n matrix ? Is dynamic programming is applicable to this problem.

Comment: Look up DFS and/or BFS algorithms. And general graph searching.

Comment: The key to thinking recursively is to think recursively.

Comment: Joke -- but wrapping your mind around recursion is actually simplifying the way you think in some way -- you narrow down the problem to just what needs to happen in a node, e.g. The key there is to think symmetrically -- think about how that same logic echoes everywhere down the hierarchy. But first start with what has to happen for a single node, and then start working your way to thinking how this repeats. Try it on paper with a drawing if you're struggling to think this way with code.

Comment: @Ike In all of these recursive jokes there is a common problem. The lack of the base case.

Comment: I think they're meant to lead to a stack overflow. :-D

Comment: @EugeneSh.: You mean `if (joke == old) return 0;`? That will happen automatically sooner or later.

Comment: How about, the key to thinking recursively is to think recursively -- until we die? I think the base case branching kills the punchline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on calculating the weight of the path that **lies ahead** of you; *don't look back.*

Start by solving a trivial edge case. Suppose you made it to the bottom row. Then there is nothing more to follow; the remaining path has weight zero.

In code:

```
int getWeight(int i, int j)
{
    int remaining = 0;
```

In any other row, you have to make a choice. Should you go left or right? Since there is no way of knowing at this point which one is best, you just have to try both directions:

```
    if (i < lastRow)
    {
        int weightLeft  = getWeight(i + 1, j);
        int weightRight = getWeight(i + 1, j + 1);
```

Notice I recursively called my own function; with a **blind faith** in that function's capability to come up with the optimal weight for the remaining path!

Having tried both directions, pick whichever came up with the highest weight:

```
        int best_j = weightLeft > weightRight ? j : j + 1;
```

Now we walk the chosen path one more time.

```
        remaining = getWeight(i + 1, best_j);
    }
```

This is not very efficient, but it helps to collect the individual steps of the optimal path. I will use a straightforward array `pathColumns`.

```
    pathColumns[i] = j;
```

Finally, we need to sum the values.

```
    return row[i][j] + remaining;
}
```

To set the whole thing in motion, just call the function, and pass it the top cell's coordinates. For practical reasons, I made all arrays base-0. So the top cell is `row[0][0]`.

```
printf("Optimal weight: %d\n", getWeight(0, 0));
```

Putting it all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 5

int pathColumns[n] = {0};

int row[n][n] =
{
    {4},
    {2, 9},
    {15, 1, 3},
    {16, 92, 41, 44},
    {8, 142, 6, 4, 8}
};

int getWeight(int i, int j)
{
    int remaining = 0;
    if (i < n-1)    /* with base-0, the last row is n-1 */
    {
        int weightLeft  = getWeight(i + 1, j);
        int weightRight = getWeight(i + 1, j + 1);
        int best_j = weightLeft > weightRight ? j : j + 1;
        remaining = getWeight(i + 1, best_j);
    }
    pathColumns[i] = j;
    return row[i][j] + remaining;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("Optimal weight: %d\n", getWeight(0, 0));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = pathColumns[i];
        printf("(%d, %d) = %d\n", i+1, j+1, row[i][j]);
        /* NOTE: +1 is a correction to bring the output back to base-1 */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Optimal weight: 255
(1, 1) = 4
(2, 1) = 2
(3, 1) = 15
(4, 2) = 92
(5, 2) = 142
```

### How it works

We want `getWeight(0, 0)` to return the heaviest path for this pyramid.

```
          4  <---- (0, 0) is our starting point
         / \
        2   9
      /  \ /  \
    15    1    3
    / \  / \  / \
  16   92   41   44
 /  \ /  \ /  \ /  \
8   142   6    4    8
```

The recursive algorithm makes two recursive calls.

- `getWeight(1, 0)` must get the heaviest path for the sub-pyramid below and to the left of our starting point.
- `getWeight(1, 1)` must get the heaviest path for the sub-pyramid below and to the right of our starting point.

The two sub-pyramids:

```
        2  <--- (1, 0)         9  <--- (1, 1)
      /  \                    /  \
    15    1                  1    3
    / \  / \                / \  / \
  16   92   41            92   41   44
 /  \ /  \ /  \          /  \ /  \ /  \
8   142   6    4      142    6    4    8
```

Assuming `getWeight(1, 0)` and `getWeight(1, 1)` return the correct weights (251 and 244, respectively), all there is left to do is pick the highest one (251) and add the top value of the big pyramid to it (4). The result is 255.

What we did is reduce a problem (calculate the maximum weight for a pyramid of height 5) so that we are left with two smaller problems to solve (calculate the maximum weight for pyramids of height 4). In the same way, we can reduce the problem for height 4 to solving the same problem for height 3. For example, `getWeight(1, 1)` will make two recursive calls `getWeight(2, 1)` and `getWeight(2, 2)`:

```
       1  <--- (2, 1)      3  <--- (2, 2)
      / \                 / \
    92   41             41   44
   /  \ /  \           /  \ /  \
142    6    4         6    4    8
```

`getWeight(1, 1)` should return 244 = 9 + max(235, 55).

Continuing this way, we eventually end up with solving the problem for pyramids of height 1. These are the values at the base of the original pyramid (8, 142, 6, 4 and 8). Here the recursion ends; a pyramid of height 1 is nothing more than a single node. The value of that node is the weight of the (only) path through that pyramid.

Comment: It is calculating all the paths from top to bottom? then it comparing which is the optimum ?

Comment: All possibilities are tried. But we don't calculate the weight of each path in full. Every time a 'subpyramid' turns out to be lighter than its neighbor, it is discarded. Only the heaviest subpaths will 'bubble up' to participate in the calculation of a 'bigger' path starting higher up the pyramid.

Comment: can u explain what are u saying about subpyramid  and how discarding the path give write solution

Comment: I added a section 'how it works' to explain the sub-pyramids; hope it helps.